# DateTime does not parse from string

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string to a `DateTime` using `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

The issue is it returns false.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date = "30/01/2014 10:02:43:096";

        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            Console.WriteLine("Yipee");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("D'oh!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If I update the date the program to use a different string date `var date = "03/01/2014 10:02:43:096";` then it works

I can't work out why it doesn't like 30 as the month...

Comment: `I can't work out why it doesn't like 30 as the month.` Really, which month is numbered 30 ?

Comment: Oh my oh my.... I've been on this for too long!!!!!! I can't believe I've spent so much time on it and asked this question. Sorry all!

Comment: @canon, Ha ha, yes it would, but I have actually tried to delete the question! I wish I could, it's a genuine silly mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** in your date string `30/01/2014 10:02:43:096` Date `30` comes first but you are parsing it as `Month` suing `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff`

**Solution :** You need to use `dd/MM/yyyy` instead of `MM/dd/yyyy` as your datestring is `30/01/2014 10:02:43:096` where date comes first.

Try This:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
```

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: Your `Date string` contains `Date` first but you are parsing  `Month` first.

Answer (score 2):

date "30/01/2014 10:02:43:096"
format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"

You are trying to get a Month of 30. :|

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
```